# Manually adding configuration products

Tags: magento2.4.2

I am new to this programme and just creating the website.

When manually adding 'non visible individually' products to a Catalog Search main item some of the list of products have a greyed out box and I am unable to tick them to add.

Is there a reason for this as they don't seem any different to the ones that I have manually added.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you need to first use the Create configurations tool to create the simple products to associate, then you need to replace the auto-generated versions with the simple products you actually want.